# Django shows wrong date for foreignkey in admin form

Tags: python, django, date, django-admin, foreign-keys

I have the model Run which has a date field, and a model Race which has a foreignkey to the Run table as follows:

```
class Run(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.date.strftime('%a %m %b %Y')

class Race(models.Model):
    run = models.ForeignKey(Run, unique=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    ...
```

I added some runs today, each with a distinct date.  The dates display correctly on the run summary admin page.  However, when adding a race, the run dropdown shows almost all dates as '08 Aug 2014' (the weekdays are, however, correct).

Does anybody know how to fix this?  I'm using python 3.4.1 and django 1.6.5.

Comment: shouldnt it be default=datetime.date.today()

Comment: @HadynDickson No, this is right. It should not be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is something trivial. Here, interpreting `self.date.strftime('%a %m %b %Y')`,

```
%a - Weekday as locale’s abbreviated name
%m - Month as a zero-padded decimal number.
%b - Month as locale’s abbreviated name
```

`%m` and `%b` both are  month representation.

Change `%b` (or `%m`) to `%d` in the `__str__` method.

Date formats [can be viewed here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

DEMO:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.today()
>>> dt = datetime.date.today()
>>> dt
datetime.date(2014, 8, 20)
>>> dt.strftime('%a %m %b %Y')
'Wed 08 Aug 2014' 
>>> dt.strftime('%a %d %b %Y')
'Wed 20 Aug 2014'
>>> dt2 = dt - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
>>> dt2
datetime.date(2014, 8, 19)
>>> dt2.strftime('%a %m %b %Y')
'Tue 08 Aug 2014'
>>> dt2.strftime('%a %d %b %Y')
'Tue 19 Aug 2014'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are showing the month 0 padded number instead of the days 0 padded number

change

```
 def __str__(self):
    return self.date.strftime('%a %m %b %Y')
```

to

```
 def __unicode__(self):
        return self.date.strftime('%a %d %b %Y')
```